# This sentence seems to use two different ways to mean "to afford" at the same time; why?

Tags: choix-de-mot

My question is about the bolded text below<sup>1</sup>:

> Après deux ans dans la famille adipeuse, un record, j’ai dû déménager
> à nouveau. Mon sens de l’initiative et mon intérêt pour la science
> n’ont pas plu. Avec les autres jeunes protégés de l’endroit, on avait
> pris l’habitude de tester nos substances psychoactives préférées sur
> Rocket, le beagle familial. Ce n’était rien de bien méchant ni
> conséquent. Nous **n’avions pas les moyens de lui offrir** les
> quantités qu’on s’envoyait nous-mêmes, mais on se cotisait souvent
> pour qu’il ait sa part.

DeepL translates the sentence that has bolded text with:

> We **couldn't afford** to give him the quantities we sent ourselves, but we often chipped in so he could have his share.

I tried looking up "moyens" in WordReference, but I couldn't find any entry that explains "avoir moyens de [faire qch]" being an expression that means "to afford"; so, instead, I searched "afford" in the English->French search in WordReference. When I did so, I got a [page](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/afford) that confused me. It says that:

- "afford [sth]" can be translated with "avoir les moyens d'acheter [qch]", or "s'offrir [qch]"
- "afford to [do sth]" can be translated with "avoir les moyens de [faire qch]", or "s'offrir [qch]"

I'm confused because the bolded text seems to be using *both* "avoir les moyens de [faire qch]", *and* "s'offrir". I'm also confused because instead of seeing "s'offrir" in the bolded text, I see "lui offrir"; but "lui" is not a form that "se" can take with a "se" verb!

Why are two different ways of meaning "to afford" being used at the same time, and why is "s'offrir" rendered as "lui offrir" in the bolded sentence?

---

<sup>1. Quote is from "La bête à sa mère", Chapter 2, by David Goudreault</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "lui" is not a form that "se" can take with a "se" verb

Don't forget that a reflexive verb is often just a transitive verb that can take a reflexive pronoun. For example, *s'habiller* can be considered just a special case of *habiller qqn*. Hence *s'offrir qqch* is just a special case of *offrir qqch à qqn*.

But anyway, I would say the problem here is WR's ambiguous break of what *s'offrir* replaces in those examples. It doesn't replace *avoir les moyens de* or *pouvoir*. It replaces *(s')acheter*, i.e. one of the things you might have the *moyens* to do or *peut* do.

I'd say the reason is that since "afford" basically means "be able to buy / pay for", if we paraphrase it as *avoir les moyens de _____* or *pouvoir _____* then there are only so many verbs that can follow and still mean "afford". *S'offrir* is common enough to warrant mention as a translation, I guess.

In short, we don't have two different ways of talking about affording, just one complete and unambiguous way to do so, plus a confusingly phrased WR entry.

Literally:

> We didn't have the means to provide him with the quantities...

Comment: *"Hence s'offrir qqch is just a special case of offrir qqch à qqn."* What confuses me is that  whenever i see "se [verb]" in WR, it always means the more specific reflexive verb use; if they mean the more general use, they would say "[verb] à qqn". am i correct in this, or instead does WR sometimes say "se [verb]" when it really means that i can use the verb non-reflexively for that entry?

Comment: also, in the WR entry for "afford [sth]", i see that "s'offrir [qch], se payer [qch]" is on the *first* line, above "avoir les moyens d'acheter [qch]"; if "s'offrir [qch]" was listed as the next line after "avoir les moyens d'acheter [qch]", i could believe that WR is trying to tell me that they really mean "avoir les moyens d'acheter [qch] (or s'offrir [qch])". so, it sounds like WR is telling me that just "s'offrir [qch]" on its own is a translation of "to afford [sth]". is this true?

Comment: s'envoyer is slang for taking drugs here. *It does not mean send*. We couldn't afford to give him the amount we took ourselves. Not such nice people giving drugs to a dog. It's amazing how far off this automated programs can be.

Comment: @silph There will often be a *light* change in meaning with the reflexive form, sometimes a more dramatic one. I would say that if WR has an entry for it, it's worth checking for a totally unique meaning (as I think I wrote in some thread between us), especially when incomprehensible transitively, but it's not a guarantee that the transitive sense won't work.

Comment: @silph Reading over the WR entry for "afford" again, I would say it's very confusing and somewhat misleading. The Collins tab does a better job with its alternatives: [avoir les moyens d'acheter] / [**pouvoir** s'offrir] / [pouvoir payer]. I wonder if their « *Note: "Afford" in this sense usually follows a derivative of "can" or "be able to."* » refers to their first translation (*s'offrir, se payer*), where it does make sense, despite it being formatted after the last one (*avoir les moyens d'acheter*), where it does not make sense.

Comment: pour lui offrir means: to give the dog [the amounts or quantities].  It is indirect object.